# Swagger won't load for .NET 6

Tags: swagger, .net-6.0, swagger-ui

After migrating to .NET 6, swagger returns a 404. What am I missing here?

In my `Configure` method:

```
// swagger
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI( options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint($"./swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    options.RoutePrefix = "info/api";
});
```

In my `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(
    options =>
    {
        // integrate xml comments
        var documentationXMLFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var documentationXMLFullPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, documentationXMLFile);
        options.IncludeXmlComments(documentationXMLFullPath);
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean *swagger returns a 404* ? What URL are you using?

Comment: What is your `description.GroupName` here?  how do you use group with swagger? Do you add any attribute on your controller level?

Comment: @Rena `description.GroupName` = `v1`. I have edited the question

Comment: @tomredfern 'https://localhost:52088/info/api'